# How to join two tables in Rails from different databases

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two databases with users tables and the foreign_key would be `a_user_id`

```
database_a.users.id, database_a.users.name
database_b.users.id, database_b.users.a_user_id
```

User class would be related with table of database_a.

```
User.joins('INNER JOIN AS b_users ON database_b.users.a_user_id = database_a.users.id')
```

It raises syntax error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax`